# how can i use both ternary operator and isnull function in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, conditional-statements, isnull

[image]

For this table, I have two null value in suburb and postcode.
I want to change 'IsValid' column into "N" if the suburb, and postcode is "Null". otherwise the 'IsValid' is "Y"

Here's my expression:

```
LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(School_Suburb))) == 0 || 
LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(School_Postcode))) == 0 || 
ISNULL(School_Suburb) || 
ISNULL(School_Postcode) ? "N" : "Y"
```

and this is the error message.

[image]

So just wondering if anyone know which part I wrote it wrong? How can I change it?

this is the screenshot of derived column edit page
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Derived Column configuration? The error message mentions an `IsValid` that is not present in the provided expression and I'd like to see if the error message is misleading or whether you have something awry in your declaration.

Comment: yea just added :)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove IsValid from the Expression and put it in the first column, currently "Derived Column 1".

The other change is that you will need to wrap the entirety of your logical ORs together with parentheses for

```
(LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(School_Suburb))) == 0 || LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(School_Postcode))) == 0 || ISNULL(School_Suburb) || ISNULL(School_Postcode)) ? "N" : "Y"
```

A good rule of thumb on expressions is that if it doesn't fit in the visible box, it's probably too long. Here, I'd break it out into three new columns split across two Derived Column Components.

[image]

Here I create two new columns `IsSuburbInvalid` and `IsSchoolInvalid` (although mislabled in the screenshot as Valid, not Invalid)

```
LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(School_Suburb))) == 0 || ISNULL(School_Suburb)
LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(School_Postcode))) == 0 || ISNULL(School_Postcode)
```

In the next Derived Column (has to be a separate component since it will use the new columns we just created), I create `IsValid` with a much easier to debug logic of

```
IsSchoolInvalid || IsSuburbInvalid ? "N" : "Y"
```

Comment: Yup, I missed a situation with the expression. Wrap it all with parenthesis

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess it's the expression I got it wrong or something, it still show the same error. I'll check it later on. Maybe it's my computer problem....

Comment: It shouldn't be a "works on my machine" type of situation. Compare what you have versus what I have. The other thing I can thing of is that you could have a conflict on the name/type of your IsValid column (might exist in your source) so call it something fresh like `IsValidCalculated`